# Why Logout navigates user to home and clears Backstack

Tags: discussion, login

As a Developer I have been observing the navigation flow of Logout navigation. Suppose I'm on a question and click on logout button then I'm navigated to Home page and not to the same page without any session. Even if I press back button from here I can't go to same question from here.

So my question is:

Should a user be navigated to homescreen or to the same page without session?

If you are sending user to home page instead of same question and clearing the backstack, what's the reason behind this?

Comment: Maybe this behavior is added to prevent [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266233/158100)

Comment: Agree with you....

Comment: But as per programming fundamentals it breaks the flow for the user and there should be a way to go to question at least. So Is this the only reason?